# Apache Nifi: PutHiveStreaming is not connecting

Tags: java, hive, apache-nifi

I have a simple process flow that follows the example: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/52856/stream-data-into-hive-like-a-king-using-nifi.html

The flow looks like this: [image]

The flow files go through the entire process but then fails to write to the Hive DB in the processor "Stream CSV to Hive."

When I look at the nifi-app.log, I get the following exception:

```
2018-03-03 00:51:33,942 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-8] 
o.a.n.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming PutHiveStreaming[id=e88d5c4e-0161-
1000-1713-79d402d400b2] Error connecting  to Hive endpoint: table olympics 
at thrift://master:9083
2018-03-03 00:51:33,947 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-8] 
o.a.n.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming PutHiveStreaming[id=e88d5c4e-0161-
1000-1713-79d402d400b2] Hive Streaming co nnect/write error, flow file will 
be penalized and routed to retry. 
org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter$ConnectFailure: Failed connecting to 
EndPoint {metaStoreUri='thrift://m aster:9083', database='default', 
table='olympics', partitionVals=[] }: 
org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming$ShouldRetryException: Hive 
Streaming connect/write error , flow file will be penalized and routed to 
retry. org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter$ConnectFailure: Failed 
connecting to EndPoint {metaStoreUri='thrift://master:9083', data 
base='default', table='olympics', partitionVals=[] }
org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming$ShouldRetryException: Hive 
Streaming connect/write error, flow file will be penalized and routed to 
retry. org.apache.nifi.util .hive.HiveWriter$ConnectFailure: Failed 
connecting to EndPoint {metaStoreUri='thrift://master:9083', 
database='default', table='olympics', partitionVals=[] }
at 
 org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.lambda$onHiveRecordsError$1(Put
    HiveStreaming.java:527)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.ExceptionHandler$OnError.lambda$andThen$0(ExceptionHandler.java:54)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.lambda$onHiveRecordError$2(PutHiveStreaming.java:545)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.ExceptionHandler.execute(ExceptionHandler.java:148)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.lambda$onTrigger$12(PutHiveStreaming.java:677)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.read(StandardProcessSession.java:2174)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.read(StandardProcessSession.java:2144)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.onTrigger(PutHiveStreaming.java:631)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.lambda$onTrigger$4(PutHiveStreaming.java:555)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.PartialFunctions.onTrigger(PartialFunctions.java:114)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.RollbackOnFailure.onTrigger(RollbackOnFailure.java:184)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.onTrigger(PutHiveStreaming.java:555)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1119)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:147)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:128)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter$ConnectFailure: Failed connecting to EndPoint {metaStoreUri='thrift://master:9083', database='default', table='olympics', partit ionVals=[] }
        at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter.<init>(HiveWriter.java:79)
        at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveUtils.makeHiveWriter(HiveUtils.java:46)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.makeHiveWriter(PutHiveStreaming.java:968)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.getOrCreateWriter(PutHiveStreaming.java:879)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.lambda$null$8(PutHiveStreaming.java:680)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.ExceptionHandler.execute(ExceptionHandler.java:127)
        ... 19 common frames omitted

Caused by: org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter$TxnBatchFailure: Failed acquiring Transaction Batch from EndPoint: {metaStoreUri='thrift://master:9083', database='default', tab le='olympics', partitionVals=[] }
        at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter.nextTxnBatch(HiveWriter.java:264)
        at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter.<init>(HiveWriter.java:73)
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.TransactionError: Unable to acquire lock on {metaStoreUri='thrift://master:9083', database='default', table='olympics', partitionV als=[] }
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$TransactionBatchImpl.beginNextTransactionImpl(HiveEndPoint.java:578)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$TransactionBatchImpl.beginNextTransaction(HiveEndPoint.java:547)
        at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter.nextTxnBatch(HiveWriter.java:261)
        ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: null
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_lock(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:3906)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.lock(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:3893)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.lock(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:1863)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:152)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.lock(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$TransactionBatchImpl.beginNextTransactionImpl(HiveEndPoint.java:573)
        ... 27 common frames omitted
```

I have the Hive metastore daemon running and the default port, 9083 is open and I can connect to it with telnet. Hive is running on the same machine as Nifi and has an entry in /etc/hosts to name it master.

I'm getting the following exception:

```
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: null.
```

Which is getting passed a null to the parent, Exception class's constructor.

I've also tried using older versions of Apache NiFi and Apache Hive. I just tried Nifi version 1.4 and Hive version 1.2.2. I'm now getting a different error:

```
    2018-03-13 19:17:20,126 INFO [put-hive-streaming-0] hive.metastore Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://master:9083
    2018-03-13 19:17:20,220 INFO [put-hive-streaming-0] hive.metastore Connected to metastore.
    2018-03-13 19:17:20,524 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] hive.metastore Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://master:9083
    2018-03-13 19:17:20,525 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] hive.metastore Connected to metastore.
    2018-03-13 19:17:21,204 WARN [put-hive-streaming-0] o.a.h.h.m.RetryingMetaStoreClient MetaStoreClient lost connection. Attempting to reconnect.
    org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Internal error processing open_txns
            at org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException.read(TApplicationException.java:111)
            at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:71)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_open_txns(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:3834)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.open_txns(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:3821)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.openTxns(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:1841)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:152)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy122.openTxns(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$TransactionBatchImpl.openTxnImpl(HiveEndPoint.java:520)
            at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$TransactionBatchImpl.<init>(HiveEndPoint.java:504)
            at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$TransactionBatchImpl.<init>(HiveEndPoint.java:461)
            at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$ConnectionImpl.fetchTransactionBatchImpl(HiveEndPoint.java:345)
            at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$ConnectionImpl.fetchTransactionBatch(HiveEndPoint.java:325)
            at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter.lambda$nextTxnBatch$2(HiveWriter.java:259)
            at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter.lambda$callWithTimeout$4(HiveWriter.java:365)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2018-03-13 19:17:22,205 INFO [put-hive-streaming-0] hive.metastore Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://master:9083
2018-03-13 19:17:22,207 INFO [put-hive-streaming-0] hive.metastore Connected to metastore.
2018-03-13 19:17:22,214 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] o.a.n.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming PutHiveStreaming[id=e88d5c4e-0161-1000-1713-79d402d400b2] Failed to create HiveWriter for endpoint: {metaStoreUri='thrift://master:9083', database='default', table='olympics', partitionVals=[] }: org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter$ConnectFailure: Failed connecting to EndPoint {metaStoreUri='thrift://master:9083', database='default', table='olympics', partitionVals=[] }
org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter$ConnectFailure: Failed connecting to EndPoint {metaStoreUri='thrift://master:9083', database='default', table='olympics', partitionVals=[] }
        at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter.<init>(HiveWriter.java:79)
        at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveUtils.makeHiveWriter(HiveUtils.java:46)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.makeHiveWriter(PutHiveStreaming.java:968)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.getOrCreateWriter(PutHiveStreaming.java:879)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.lambda$null$8(PutHiveStreaming.java:680)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.ExceptionHandler.execute(ExceptionHandler.java:127)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.lambda$onTrigger$12(PutHiveStreaming.java:677)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.read(StandardProcessSession.java:2174)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.read(StandardProcessSession.java:2144)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.onTrigger(PutHiveStreaming.java:631)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.lambda$onTrigger$4(PutHiveStreaming.java:555)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.PartialFunctions.onTrigger(PartialFunctions.java:114)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.RollbackOnFailure.onTrigger(RollbackOnFailure.java:184)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.onTrigger(PutHiveStreaming.java:555)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1119)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:147)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:128)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter$TxnBatchFailure: Failed acquiring Transaction Batch from EndPoint: {metaStoreUri='thrift://master:9083', database='default', table='olympics', partitionVals=[] }
        at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter.nextTxnBatch(HiveWriter.java:264)
        at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter.<init>(HiveWriter.java:73)
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.TransactionBatchUnAvailable: Unable to acquire transaction batch on end point: {metaStoreUri='thrift://master:9083', database='default', table='olympics', partitionVals=[] }
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$TransactionBatchImpl.<init>(HiveEndPoint.java:511)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$TransactionBatchImpl.<init>(HiveEndPoint.java:461)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$ConnectionImpl.fetchTransactionBatchImpl(HiveEndPoint.java:345)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$ConnectionImpl.fetchTransactionBatch(HiveEndPoint.java:325)
        at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter.lambda$nextTxnBatch$2(HiveWriter.java:259)
        at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter.lambda$callWithTimeout$4(HiveWriter.java:365)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Internal error processing open_txns
        at org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException.read(TApplicationException.java:111)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:71)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_open_txns(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:3834)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.open_txns(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:3821)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.openTxns(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:1841)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:152)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy122.openTxns(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$TransactionBatchImpl.openTxnImpl(HiveEndPoint.java:520)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$TransactionBatchImpl.<init>(HiveEndPoint.java:504)
        ... 9 common frames omitted
```

Comment: So after looking through the source, it turns out the exception is being thrown inside of the Apache Thrift library. The exception is thrown when the socket's InputStream's read method returns a negative number. This throws an TTransportException with the integer value for End of File (4). This integer is saved in a member variable of the exception. Nothing gets passed up to the parent constructor which is why it says null.

Answer (score 0):

What version of NiFi/HDF are you using and what kind/version of Hadoop cluster are you connecting to (HDP, e.g.)? It is a known issue that Apache NiFi will not work with HDP Hive starting with HDP 2.5 (or maybe 2.4), you would have to download the NiFi-only distro of Hortonworks Data Flow in order to make it work.

Comment: NiFi is version 1.4. Hive is version 2.3.2. My Hadoop cluster is a two-node cluster, running Hadoop version: 2.9.0.

Comment: Apache NiFi? I’m guessing it won’t work against Hive 2.3.2 because NiFi’s Hive processors are based on Hive 1.2.1, there were probably Thrift changes between the two versions. You can try the HDF NiFi, it has version 1.2.1000 which is closer to 2.x and might work.

Comment: what makes you say Hive processors are based on Hive 1.2.1? Would you please provide a link to the HDF NiFi?

Comment: I wrote them :) check the top-level pom.xml in the NiFi source code for that version, hive.version. For the link you can google Hortonworks Data Flow, then go to downloads and choose NiFi-only

Comment: It looks like the version of Nifi on Hortonworks is version 1.5.0.

Comment: True, but HDF NiFi builds with HDP Hive JARs so the Hive processors may be closer in compatibility with Hive 2.x

Comment: So I just remembered the reason I moved to 1.4 from 1.5 was because of this bug that will be fixed in 1.6: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4761. I'm running NiFi on an AWS EC2 instance. When I try to go to the page, I get the error: "The request contained an invalid host header [<hostname>:8080] in the request [/nifi]. Check for request manipulation or third-party intercept."

Comment: I was able to get version 1.5.0 to come up by adding the hostname to the nifi.properties: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/164783/nifi-15-system-error-invalid-host-header.html

Comment: However I'm still getting the same error. It looks like NiFi can't get a lock on the metastore.

Comment: It's probably not compatible then. We'd need a new Hive bundle to support Hive 2.x. Since 3.0 is coming out soon I am working on a Hive 3 bundle under NIFI-4963, perhaps it will be backwards compatible.